# Клавиши управления видео работают везде на странице, а не только на видео

Tags: javascript, видео, события, controls, focus

Не понимаю, почему мой примитивный код не работает должным образом.Ниже приведены 2 куска кода в котором я проверяю фокус, а во втором просто выполняю функцию при нажатии клавиши(таких много у меня).Так вот, почему при клике в текстовое поле которое находится над видео при вводе поискового запроса, фокус как бы остается и принимаются клавиши, которыми я управляю видео. Получается, что я ввожу запрос и управляю видео одновременно, помогите пожалуйста.

```
 window.onload = intializePlayer;
var videoBox = document.getElementById("video_player_box");
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var isClickInside = video.contains(event.target);

  if (!isClickInside) {
    videoBox.blur();
  } else {
    videoBox.focus();
  }
});

function playPauseControl(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 86) {
    playPause();
  }
}
```

Структура HTML(точнее ее часть, так как она очень большая):

```
<div id="video_player_box">
  <video controls="controls" id="video"  poster="movies/photo/<?php echo  $photovideo;?>">
     <source src="movies/<?php echo  $way .= $type;  ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>   
  </video>
   <div id="video_controls_bar">
    <div class="wrap">
       <input id="seekslider" type="range"  class="range"  min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" oninput="vidSeek(this.value)" onchange="vidSeek(this.value)">
   </div>

   <button id="playpausebutton"></button>   
   <button id="stopbutton"></button>
   <button id="mutebtn"></button>      
   <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" oninput="setvolume(this.value)" onchange="setvolume(this.value)">
   <span id="curtimetext">00:00 </span><span id="separator"> / </span><span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>   


  <button id="fullscreenbtn"></button>
    <div class="dropdownvideo">
  <button id="qualitybtn" onclick="QualityMenu()" class="dropbtn"></button>
  <div id="Dropdown" class="dropdown-content-video">
    <a id="HQ" href="#">HQ</a>
    <a id="MQ" href="#">MQ</a>
    <a id="LQ" href="#">LQ</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: покажите структуру html

Comment: Добавил структуру.